# Adjust BitmapDrawable or bitmap dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a tab-like interface where I will switch views by sliding left/right. I display to the user what page they are on by adding a blue glow to the back of the tab icon shown here:

[image]

---

I did this by creating a custom view that will draw the background glow (if the tab is selected) and then the icon. My issue is that the **glow is too large**. All I need to do is to make it smaller so the sides don't get clipped like they are now (the glow overlaps the page on the bottom by design).

- The glow was created using a shape drawable in XML (just a simple radial gradient).
- I have tried changing the size of the shape in XML but it always comes out the same. I tried adjusting attributes under  and tried adjusting the height and width under  too.

---

Constructor:

```
public TabIconView(Context context, Bitmap tab)
{
    super(context);

    back = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_blue_glow);
    this.tab = tab;
}
```

onMeasure and onDraw:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    setMeasuredDimension(tab.getWidth() * 2, tab.getHeight() * 2);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    width = getMeasuredWidth();
    height = getMeasuredHeight();

    if (selected)
        canvas.drawBitmap(back, (width - back.getWidth()) / 2, (height - back.getHeight()) / 2, null);

    canvas.drawBitmap(tab, (width - tab.getWidth()) / 2, (height - tab.getHeight()) / 2, null);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the versions of Canvas.drawBitmap() lets you specified the width and height that you want the bitmap to have when drawn on screen. You could also simply rescale the bitmap when you load it (the Bitmap class has methods to create scaled versions of bitmaps.)

Comment: I actually ran across Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() about an hour after positing this. Worked perfectly! I'll post the code later when it allows me to. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In case anybody wants to know...

```
public TabIconView(Context context, Bitmap tab)
{
    super(context);
    int backSize = (int) (42 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + .5f);

    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_blue_glow);
    back = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, backSize, backSize, false);
    this.tab = tab;
}
```

I had to create a scaled bitmap from the bitmap that was generated from the shapedrawable.